# OpenCL Invalid Kernel Name

Tags: kernel, opencl

I'm converting OpenCL code from my Mac to a Linux box with an NVIDIA Tesla K20c card and have run into a snag when building a simple kernel.  My kernel code is this:

```
char kernel[1024] =
"#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64: enable \
                                              \
kernel void diff(global double* u,            \
                  int N,                      \
                  double dx,                  \
                  global double* du)          \
{                                             \
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);              \
    int ip = (i+1)%N;                         \
    int im = (i+N-1)%N;                       \
    du[i] = (u[ip] - u[im])/dx/2.;            \
}";
```

I call this with:

```
const char* srccode = kernel;
cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &srccode, NULL, &err);
err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "diff", &err);
```

`clBuildProgram` returns `CL_SUCCESS` and the log from `clBuildProgramInfo` is empty, but `clCreateKernel` returns `CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME`.  Any idea why?  I've been banging at this a while and can't find anything.  If I change all the doubles to floats and remove the pragma the problem goes away and it works correctly.  So is the pragma to blame?  If so, how do I do it correctly?

Comment: Just remove pragma, not doubles, if it gives same error, look for a proper line feed characer for your device compiler(could be different than your programming environment).

Answer (score 3):

The whole `kernel[1024]` string will end up in one line which is fine for the kernel definition but not for `pragma` - there you need the end line character. Fixed version would look like this:

```
char kernel[1024] =
"#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64: enable \n\
                                              \
kernel void diff(global double* u,            \
                  int N,                      \
                  double dx,                  \
                  global double* du)          \
{                                             \
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);              \
    int ip = (i+1)%N;                         \
    int im = (i+N-1)%N;                       \
    du[i] = (u[ip] - u[im])/dx/2.;            \
}";
```